# базовый адрес потока

Tags: c++, windows

Добрый день! Подскажите есть ли возможность получить базовый адрес потока по thread ID. Необходимо для определения из какого модуля процесса запущен поток.

Comment: @Abyx Спасибо! Windows. Можно поподробнее как добраться до стека потока? Я не силен в работе с адресным пространством процесса. Конечная цель определить по id потока какому модулю он принадлежит!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205981/windows-c-stack-trace-from-a-running-app

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать NtQueryInformationThread:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Winternl.h>

LPVOID GetThreadAddress(DWORD thid){

    HANDLE thread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,thid);
    if(thread == NULL || thread == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {wprintf(L"OpenThread failed");return NULL;}

    HMODULE hm=LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");
    if(hm == NULL){ wprintf (L"LoadLibrary failed\n"); return NULL;}

    NTSTATUS (__stdcall *NtQueryInformationThread ) (IN HANDLE , IN THREADINFOCLASS , OUT PVOID, IN ULONG, OUT PULONG OPTIONAL )  
        = (NTSTATUS  (__stdcall *) (IN HANDLE , IN THREADINFOCLASS , OUT PVOID ,  IN ULONG , OUT PULONG OPTIONAL))
        GetProcAddress(hm,"NtQueryInformationThread");  
    if(NtQueryInformationThread == NULL){ wprintf (L"GetProcAddress failed\n"); return NULL;}

    LPVOID info=NULL;   
    NTSTATUS ntstatus = NtQueryInformationThread(thread,(THREADINFOCLASS)9 ,&info,sizeof(info),NULL);
    if(ntstatus != 0) {wprintf (L"NtQueryInformationThread NTSTATUS 0x%x\n",(UINT)ntstatus); return NULL;}
    else return info;

}
```

При наличии отладочных символов также можно получить стек с помощью DbgHelp и пройти его до тех пор, пока не встретится системная функция создания потока (BaseThreadInitThunk):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include "DbgHelp.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Dbghelp.lib")

const int MaxNameLen = 256;

LPVOID GetThreadAddress2( DWORD thid )
{
    BOOL    result;
    HANDLE  process;
    HANDLE thread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,thid);

    if(thread == NULL || thread == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {printf("OpenThread failed");return 0;}

    CONTEXT cont={0};
    cont.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS|CONTEXT_INTEGER|CONTEXT_CONTROL;    
    SuspendThread(thread);
    result = GetThreadContext(thread,&cont);
    if(result == FALSE)  {printf("GetThreadContext failed\n");return 0;}
    ResumeThread(thread);

    STACKFRAME64        stack;
    ULONG               frame;    
    DWORD64             displacement;

    char buffer[sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + MAX_SYM_NAME * sizeof(TCHAR)];
    char name[ MaxNameLen ];

    PSYMBOL_INFO pSymbol = (PSYMBOL_INFO)buffer;

    ULONG64 prevaddr = 0;
    char prevname[MaxNameLen];

    memset( &stack, 0, sizeof( STACKFRAME64 ) );

    process                = GetCurrentProcess();

    displacement           = 0;
#if !defined(_M_AMD64)
    stack.AddrPC.Offset    = (cont).Eip;
    stack.AddrPC.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;
    stack.AddrStack.Offset = (cont).Esp;
    stack.AddrStack.Mode   = AddrModeFlat;
    stack.AddrFrame.Offset = (cont).Ebp;
    stack.AddrFrame.Mode   = AddrModeFlat;
#endif

    result = SymInitialize( process, NULL, TRUE ); //загружаем символы
    if(result == FALSE)  {printf("SymInitialize failed\n"); return 0;}

    for( frame = 0; ; frame++ )
    {
        //получаем следующий вызов из стека
        result = StackWalk64
        (
#if defined(_M_AMD64)
            IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64
#else
            IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386
#endif
            ,
            process,
            thread,
            &stack,
            &cont,
            NULL,
            SymFunctionTableAccess64,
            SymGetModuleBase64,
            NULL
        );

        if( !result ) break;        

        //получаем имя символа для адреса
        pSymbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
        pSymbol->MaxNameLen = MAX_SYM_NAME;
        result = SymFromAddr(process, ( ULONG64 )stack.AddrPC.Offset, &displacement, pSymbol);
        if(result == FALSE)  {printf("SymFromAddr failed");continue;}        

        if(lstrcmpA(pSymbol->Name,"BaseThreadInitThunk") == 0){                       
            break;
        }     

        lstrcpyA(prevname,pSymbol->Name);
        prevaddr = ( ULONG64 )pSymbol->Address;
    }

    return (LPVOID)prevaddr;
}
```